# CSS position:fixed not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I coded some things which access on this url.

CSS Codes

```
   #hideshow {
    background-image: url("../img/thematic.png");
    position: fixed;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 100px 0px 10px 100px;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.7;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 1;
}

#pnlThematic {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    border: dotted;
}

#pnlThematicParent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="pnlThematicParent">
        <div id="pnlThematic">
            <a id="hideshow">aa</a>
            <h3>Section 1</h3>             
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQueryCodes

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        var wWidth = $(document).width();

        var pnlThematicWidth = $("#pnlThematicParent").outerWidth();
        $("#pnlThematicParent").css({ 'margin-left': wWidth - (pnlThematicWidth - 8), 'overflow': 'hidden' });

        var elementWidth = $("#hideshow").width();
        $("a").css({ 'margin-left': -(elementWidth * 2) });

        $("a").on("click", function (ev) {
            var isVisible = $(ev.target).parent().is(":visible");
            $(ev.target).parent().animate({
                marginLeft: -(parseFloat($(ev.target).parent().css('marginLeft'))) < 0 ? 0 : $("#pnlThematicParent").outerWidth()
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3DS3/7/

I Wantto open and close panel with red circle but when opening panel with clicking red circle right of the screen in chrome red circles position not changed but in ie and firefox red circles position changing with parent divs position. when open the example please click red circle on right of the screen.
Thanks for your interesting
Good Works Everyone

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: please format your code and remove the parts that aren't relevant - we don't need the lorem ipsum and such. also, what should it do? the css property position:fixed is fully supported in the latest chrome (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed)

Comment: Hi; I apologize for lorem ipsum. 
When circles parent div's left-margin changed circles position not changing but in ie and firefox it changes
If you test it in jsfiddle it works in ie and firefox but not working in chrome
thanks for your interesting 
good works

Comment: @user3635801 thanks, I tested on FF and Chrome and see what you mean. This has nothing to do with position:fixed however. Position fixed behaves as expected for your code on both browsers. What's happening is that the red circle won't move to the left when you click it. I'd suggest you try animating the left property of the red circle rather than the margin-left of its parent.

Comment: this is a jquery question, I'm retagging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Andrew's answer u need to make changes in your css

**css**

```
#hideshow {
      background-color: #F0F8FF;
      background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg");
      background-size: cover;
      border-radius: 100px 0 10px 100px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888888;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 40px;
      left: -20px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      padding: 2px 4px;
      position: absolute;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
      width: 10px;
    }

    #pnlThematic {
      border: medium dotted;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #pnlThematicParent {
      height: 300px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      width: 150px;
    }
```

and a little change in ur script too

**script**

```
var wWidth = $(document).width();

$('#pnlThematic').css({marginLeft:  -(parseFloat($('#pnlThematic').css('marginLeft'))) < 0 ? 0 : $("#pnlThematicParent").outerWidth()});

var elementWidth = $("#hideshow").width();

$("a").on("click", function (ev) {
    var isVisible = $(ev.target).parent().is(":visible");
    $(ev.target).parent().animate({
        marginLeft: -(parseFloat($(ev.target).parent().css('marginLeft'))) < 0 ? 0 : $("#pnlThematicParent").outerWidth()
    });
});
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/rEu2j/)

Note: Instead of making handle fixed make parent div fixed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `position:fixed` but instead use `position:absolute`. You will need to also set a parent element such as `#pnlThematic` to `position:relative` to make it work.

This is because you are not trying to position the link fixed to the page, but rather relative to the parent element.

You will need to make a few more edits to your css to make it show properly, but I think that's essentially where your problem lies.